# Responsive code for google DFP

Tags: google-dfp

I am using google dfp on a responsive site.
I have called

```
googletag.pubads().display(); 
googletag.pubads().refresh();
```

on window resize

But it doesnt seem to work.
I have already defined different slots for mobiles and tablets, but it works on page load and not window resize.
Can someone please suggest how this can be achieved? Any links to live responsive sites using google dfp will also be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
// <![CDATA[
var resizeTimer; function resizer() {
googletag.pubads().refresh([window.Leaderslot]); }
window.addEventListener("resize", function(){   clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
resizeTimer = setTimeout(resizer, 250); });
// ]]>;
```

Take a look here for the orginal code and explanations - http://exisweb.net/how-to-use-google-adsense-on-a-responsive-website